# C expression evaluating differently on two different compilers

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, atmelstudio

I have code that is running differently between GCC and Atmel Studio:

```
uint32_t tc = 107900;
int8_t   m  = 59;

tc = tc - (m*1800);
```

On GCC, the result in `tc` is 1700, as intended.

With AtmelStudio, the result in `tc` is 132772, which is not correct.

The problem seems to be that the `m*1800` term is being computed with the limited precision of m with AtmelStudio.

My question is, which compiler is doing it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: I would imagine that casting `m` to `uint32_t` in the expression (i.e. `tc = tc - ((uint32_t)m * 1800)`) would produce the desired results, but I'm not sure that it's required by the C language specs.

Comment: ... or use `(m*1800L)` since the arithmetic product of 59*1800 does not fit in the _minimum_ C specified `int` range of -32767 to +32767 but does fit in the  _minimum_ C specified `long` range.

Comment: Obviously this compiler uses 16 bit integers by default. Expected behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are doing it correctly. The expression `m * 1800` will be calculated as type `int`. If `int` is 32 bits, then it will be `106200`. If `int` is 16 bits, which is a perfectly acceptable way to implement a C compiler, then it's `-24872`.

Comment: Actually it's undefined in the latter case.

Comment: Not perfect, only standard, but it is enough for a +1 :-)

Comment: Thanks, so it has to do with the default type-size of the constant.

Comment: @NXT: Not really. It has to do with the default size of int, which will be overridden here by a long constant.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that on AtmelStudio, `int` is 16-bit, so `m*1800` overflows, invoking undefined behavior. In your case, the behavior the compiler gave was probably reduction modulo 65536 into the range [-32768,32767], yielding `-24872`. Then `tc - (m*1800)` is 132772.

To avoid this you need to cast either `m` or `1800` to `uint32_t` or some other type (e.g. `long`) where the result won't overflow before doing the multiplication.